# How to create mockito object from flutter singleton class?

Tags: flutter, mocking, flutter-test

I'm trying to write unit tests for my flutter application. I'm using the [Mockito package](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito). I had some problem with the null safety requirement for the new flutter versions. The Mockito requires the new flutter version but lots of other packages I use are incompatible, so I just put the `// @dart=2.9` on top of all my files. Not sure if that could be source of some problems.

So here I would like to test that when the `onPressedSubmit` method is called on the SliderRatingPage (that's what happens when the user taps a certain button), that the application will call the database. Specifically it should call the `insertRow` method defined in the `DatabaseHelper` class.

Here I would expect that annotating the test case with `@GenerateMocks([DatabaseHelper])` will effectively mock out every call to DatabaseHelper class, therefor I could use `verify` to test that the `insertRow` method was called, just as is written in the code below. But the `DatabaseHelper` is apparently a non-mockito object, as that is the error message I get when trying to run the test.

What is then the correct way to write a test that would do what I intended?

```
// @dart=2.9
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:my_app/uidesign/page_slider_rating.dart'; //SliderRatingPage class
import 'package:my_app/database/database_helpers.dart';  //DatabaseHelper class, singleton

@GenerateMocks([DatabaseHelper])
void main() {
  test('onPressedSubmit calls database.', () async {
    SliderRatingPage page = SliderRatingPage();
    page.createState().onPressedSubmit();

    verify(DatabaseHelper.instance.insertRow(any));
  });
}
```